# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT does not result in error when database calls are from the same connection

Tags: mysql, exception, locking

I would like my stored proc to throw an error when `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` encounters a locked row ([as it is intended to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#innodb-locking-reads-nowait-skip-locked)). My problem is that my web API (which is calling the procedures) seems to be making all SQL calls on the same MySQL connection, so `NOWAIT` isn't causing an error... the stored proc just waits for the lock to be released on the row.

When I call the procedure at the same time from two separate connections, it properly throws the error `[HY000][3572] Statement aborted because lock(s) could not be acquired immediately and NOWAIT is set.`

Is there a way to have the locking read throw an error when making multiple database calls from the same connection?

Comment: It sounds like you've enabled connection pooling in your webserver.

Comment: Yes - I would like to keep connection pooling in the web server

Comment: But this is one of the implications of connection pooling, they share the same session.

Comment: Essentially I am inquiring if, on the MySQL side, there is a way to get the desired behavior.

Comment: I don't think so. This is the kind of problem that connection pooling raises.